# How do i convert text capture files back to pcap files?

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I have opened Wireshark, selected the *a.pcap* file, and then went to File->Export and chose (K12 text file) to convert to text. Result is *a.txt* file.

How can I convert back *a.txt* file to original pcap file.

I want to edit some time stamps in *a.txt* file and convert back to pcap file.
I don't want to disturb any data.

Comment: Not sure how to convert txt to pcap, but you can edit the time with `editcap -t` on the command-line. It's a Wireshark tool so you should already have it. 
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html

Comment: If you can manage to convert the K12 text file into a format that [`text2pcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html) supports, then you should be able to convert **that** file back into a pcap file either by `text2pcap` or from Wireshark directly.  Unfortunately, neither `text2pcap` nor Wireshark currently supports any other formats than what is documented in the `text2pcap` man page.